# Batch Process updates a query with an input value

Tags: mysql, sql, batch-file

I am looking to create a batch process that I run every month that will update a mysql table I have. I have a query worked out but there is one part that will change every month.

I was thinking something like a prompt when I start the batch process in command line that would allow me to enter in the value that is changing and then have it some how update my query with this value.

Comment: Could you show an example, including a reason why you would be unable to store this value in another table, populated in advance of your batch process starting?  *(Which would also give you an audit trail.)*

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with `set /p` or make the changing value an input parameter to the batch file when you call it.

Set /p example

```
@echo off
setlocal

set /p var=Enter changing value
mysql -h hostname -u username -p db_name -e "Select * from table where something='%%var%%'"
```

Input example:

with a batch file named myquery.bat:

from cmd line `C:\>myquery.bat input`

```
set var="%~1"
mysql -h hostname -u username -p db_name -e "Select * from table where something='%%var%%'"
```